# System.ObjectDisposedException: This resolve operation has already ended

Tags: c#, autofac

I have the following configuration in Autofac:

```
builder.Register<ServiceFactory>(x => y => x.Resolve<IComponentContext>().Resolve(y));
```

With this configuration I get the error:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: This resolve operation has already
>   ended.
>       When registering components using lambdas, the IComponentContext 'c' parameter to the lambda cannot be stored. 
>       Instead, either resolve IComponentContext again from 'c', or resolve a Func<> based factory to create subsequent components from.

If I use the following than it works:

```
builder.Register<ServiceFactory>(x => {
  IComponentContext context = x.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
  return y => context.Resolve(y);
});
```

Can't this configuration be made in one code line?

What am I missing?

Comment: You aren't missing anything.  The component context can't be resolved from within the inner lambda.  It has to be resolved outside, and used within.

Answer (score -1):

Your first configuration looks quite similar to the second but it differ on when `IComponentContext` is resolved.

Let me restructure a little bit your first configuration without changing logic.

```
builder.Register<ServiceFactory>(x => 
{ 
    return y => x.Resolve<IComponentContext>().Resolve(y)
});
```

In the first example, you are registering lambda which

1. Returns lambda which:

   1.1 Resolve IComponentContext

   1.2 Call Resolve on IComponentContext instance and return result

Let's compare it to the second configuration.

```
builder.Register<ServiceFactory>(x => {
  IComponentContext context = x.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
  return y => context.Resolve(y);
});
```

In the second example, you are registering lambda which

1. Resolve IComponentContext and assign it to variable 'context'
2. Returns lambda which captures variable context and:

   2.1 Call Resolve on variable context and return result

So it differs on moment of resolving IComponentContext.